# extra call 'color' in init

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Can someone explain why I get an error on the second

```
super.init()
```

and not the first one?
Or should I structure this differently to avoid the error?

```
class Ground : SKSpriteNode {
init (length : CGFloat, xposition : CGFloat) {
    let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Ground")
    let size = CGSize(width: length, height: 10)
    super.init(texture: texture, color: nil, size: size)
    self.position = CGPoint(x: xposition, y: CGFloat(5))
}
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
} }

class Platform : SKSpriteNode {
init (length : CGFloat, xposition : CGFloat, yposition : CGFloat) {
    let texture = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Platform")
    let size = CGSize(width: length, height: 10)
    super.init(texture: texture, color: nil, size: size)
    self.position = CGPoint(x: xposition, y: yposition)
}
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
} }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You can't run `super.init(texture: SKSpriteNode, color: nil, size: CGSize)` the texture has to be an `SKTexture`

Answer (score 1):

Because you wrote `let texture = SKSpriteNode(...)` in the second method and `let texture = SKTexture(...)` in the first.

To make it more obvious lets put these two calls underneath each other:

```
let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Ground")
let texture = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Platform")
```

I don't know a lot about SpriteKit, but I assume that `SKSpriteNode` in the second one is a typo, and it should be `SKTexture` as well.

And the compiler wants to complain about the texture parameter being the wrong type, but it gets confused, so it complains about color.

Comment: Yep. It seems to be a typo. Could also use the SKSpriteNode and just run `texture.texture!` but better off just using an `SKTexture` in the first place.